# Different routing rules for a particular user using firewall mark and ip rule

Tags: iptables, iproute2

Running Ubuntu 12.10 on amd64.

I'm trying to set up different routing rules for a particular user.  I understand that the right way to do this is to create a firewall rule that marks the packets for that user, and add a routing rule for that mark.  Just to get testing going, I've added a rule that discards all packets as unreachable:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 unreachable
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

With this rule in place and all firewall chains in all tables empty and policy ACCEPT, I can still ping remote hosts just fine as any user.

If I then add a rule to mark all packets and try to ping Google, it fails as expected

```
# iptables -t mangle -F OUTPUT
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 0x01
# ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

If I restrict this rule to the VPN user, it seems to have no effect.

```
# iptables -t mangle -F OUTPUT
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 0x01 -m owner --uid-owner vpn
# sudo -u vpn ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.78.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wg-in-f103.1e100.net (173.194.78.103): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=36.6 ms
```

But it appears that the mark is being set, because if I add a rule to drop these packets in the firewall, it works:

```
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j DROP -m mark --mark 0x01
# sudo -u vpn ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping is setuid so that it has permission to construct ICMP packets - presumably this also prevents it from picking up the firewall mark.  If I try this on a test box, and use dig or telnet in my test cases, the policy route looks to kick in properly.

Comment: Indeed, I observe the same thing.  Still leaves a mystery as to why the DROP rule stops the ping from working, but means I can make progress on this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it has stopped the ping - the error you get there is with the DNS lookup.  Try pinging an IP in that test case instead of looking up a name.